# Why don't my Google Analytics custom segmentation visit numbers match up?

Tags: google-analytics

I have three main areas of my site and want to track total usage as well as breakdowns of the three parts. I am trying to segment the "type" of use on each page using a custom variable as such:

```
['_setCustomVar',1,'Visitor Type','Unknown',1]
```

Visitor type can be one of three values: "Unknown", "Reader" or "publisher".

Every page has this value set. Now when I look at my analytics chart and chose all three segments, the individual values do not match the sum. I've double checked the pages to make sure the custom var is there.

[image: Google Analytics Screenshot]

Comment: *@Hates_* - You might want to specify a timeframe which does not include the weeks prior to the addition of your custom variables.

Comment: I think you might just be dealing with the unreliability of Google Analytics Custom Variables, since they don't make their own HTTP request, but piggy back on other ones.

Answer (score 1):

I can't take the credit for this, but the answer danlefree gave in the comments seems to explain why the numbers don't seem to add up.